# beginner: visual basic build cpp

Tags: visual-c++

Disclaimer: I am a total beginner to Visual Basic but code a bit in python and Drupal

I need to compile this C++ app (http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=git&group_id=227253). I succesfully cloned from git, but how do I compile it (get the .exe) in Visual Basic 2008 or 2010 Express?

I have tried this:

```
1. Open Visual Basic 2008 Express, File, New, Windows Form Application (naive assumption, which should I choose?)
2. Dragged the contents of the git clone into the Solution Explorer Window (which Adds files)
3. Click Build menu
```

After that I'm lost. Any help is appreciated! This project uses cmake if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compile a C++ program in Visual Basic 2008 Express.

You must download Visual C++.  Or purchase Visual Studio 2010 Pro (which includes all of VB, C++, C# and the web tools).

If you've got the bandwidth, I'd encourage you to get this .iso:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso

If you're interested in the "bleeding edge", MSVS 2011 beta is available here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads

Otherwise, if you just want to compile some C+ code on a Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, get this:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

Answer (score 1):

You need Visual C++, not Visual Basic. They are separate languages.

Comment: Thank you. So I dragged the git folder to Microsoft C++ 2010 Express, enabled the Tools, Settings, Expert, then clicked Build but now get an error: b:\git\home\x\diyebc\st\application.cpp(39): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
1>  Generating Code...